# No line-in sound on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I suddenly got no sound using the line-in on my laptop and I do not know why. I know this isn't a hardware issue, because the line-in worked fine when booting from a USB.

Restarting pulse and alsa did nothing, and using `alsamixer` did not help as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and adding:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```